# Incoherencia de accesibilidad: el tipo de parámetro es menos accesible que el método 34 20

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un problema que no entiendo mucho por qué aparece este error, en los métodos Guardar y ObtenerListado.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace estacionamiento
{
    public class Bd
    {
        private SqlConnection conexion;
        private SqlCommand instruccion;

        public Bd()
        {
            this.conexion = new SqlConnection();
            this.conexion.ConnectionString = @"Data source=(local); Initial Catalog=Estacionamientos;Integrated Security=true";
            this.instruccion = new SqlCommand();
            this.instruccion.Connection = this.conexion;
        }

        private void Conectar()
        {
            this.conexion.Open();
        }

        private void Desconectar()
        {
            this.conexion.Close();
        }

        public int Guardar(EntidadEstacionamiento estacionamiento)
        {
            string Resultado = "";

            this.instruccion.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            this.instruccion.CommandText = "Guardar";

            this.instruccion.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NombreDueño", estacionamiento.NombreDueño));
            this.instruccion.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Modelo", estacionamiento.Modelo));
            this.instruccion.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Placas", estacionamiento.Placas));
            this.instruccion.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@HoraLlegada", estacionamiento.HoraLlegada));
            this.instruccion.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@HoraSalida", estacionamiento.HoraSalida));

            this.Conectar();
            //Guardar asistente
            int IDAsistente = Convert.ToInt32(this.instruccion.ExecuteScalar());


            this.Desconectar();

            return IDAsistente;
        }

        public List<EntidadEstacionamiento> ObtenerListado()
        {
            List<EntidadEstacionamiento> Lista = new List<EntidadEstacionamiento>();
            this.instruccion.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            this.instruccion.CommandText = "ObtenerListado";
            this.Conectar();
            SqlDataReader reader = this.instruccion.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                EntidadEstacionamiento Entidad = new EntidadEstacionamiento();
                Entidad.ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"].ToString());
                Entidad.NombreDueño = reader["nombre_dueno"].ToString();
                Entidad.Placas = reader["placas"].ToString();
                Entidad.Modelo = reader["modelo"].ToString();
                Entidad.HoraLlegada = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Celular"].ToString());
                Entidad.HoraSalida = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["Celular"].ToString());
                Lista.Add(Entidad);
            }
            reader.Close();
            this.Desconectar();
            return Lista;
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que Bd es una clase pública, pero los métodos ObtenerListado y Guardar están usando la clase EntidadEstacionamiento que no es publica.

Entonces c# se queja diciendo que para poder hacer públicos esos métodos necesita que los datos que recibe y devuelve también lo sean, y como EntidadEstacionamiento no lo es... da un error.

Espero haber sido lo suficientemente claro.

Answer (score 0):

Como ya te lo comentaron, la *clase* y sus *miembros* deben ser **públicos**, esto lo logras de la siguiente manera:

```
public class EntidadEstacionamiento
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string NombreDueño { get; set; }
    public string Placas { get; set; }
    public string Modelo { get; set; }
    public string HoraLlegada { get; set; } // Sería mejor un TimeSpan ya que cada elemento
    public string HoraSalida { get; set; }  // debe ser coherente con lo que expresa.
}
```

Observa que tanto la clase como sus elementos son precedidos por la palabra [`public`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/public), esta es el [modificador de acceso](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers); de no ponerlo, el compilador asume su acceso como [`internal`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal) y origina este tipo de problemas.
Usando `public` podrás acceder a los elementos de esa clase desde cualquier otro punto de la aplicación sin problemas.